# Create a dice chart

Tags: c

I am facing a problem right now and can't seem to solve it. Whenever I start my code I get a segmentation fault. My aim is to roll two dice. The value is generated by a random number. I want to roll 10000 times and save the values within an array, so I can create a little chart at the end which will show the diced the values. I appreciate any help and hints on how to solve the problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DICE      2
#define DICEEYES  (DICE * 6) -DICE +1
#define COUNT     10000

int diceRoll(int dice);

int main(void)
{
  srand(time(0));
  int valuesOfRoll[DICEEYES] = { 0 };
  for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
  {
    int index = diceRoll(DICE) - DICE;
    valuesOfRoll[index]++;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < DICEEYES; i++)
  {
    if(valuesOfRoll[i] < 1) continue;
    printf("The number %2d was rolled %4d times\r\n", i + DICE, valuesOfRoll[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

int diceRoll(int dice)
{
  int sum;
  for(int i = 0; i < dice; i++)
  {
    sum += rand() % 6 + 1;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: C != C++, plus have you tried debugging and *know* where it crashes?

Comment: I have to admit that I am a newbie. Haven't tried it so far.

Comment: Please turn on full warnings on your compiler (try with and without optimizations), it should tell you at least one problem. And please edit your tags, this looks & feels like C, not C++.

Comment: `int valuesOfRoll[DICEEYES]` -> `int valuesOfRoll[pow(6, DICE)];` in other words, `36` in this case

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't get your comment to be honest

Comment: 1) 2 dice can have a sum value that ranges from 2 through 12, not 2 through 11. the calculation for DICEEYES is wrong.  2) this line: 'sum += rand() % 6 + 1;' will have Precedence and order of evaluation problems.  suggest: 'sum += (rand() % 6) + 1;'

Comment: It's a good idea to test new functions in isolation. After you wrote `diceRoll` you should have tested it before wrapping it in loops and arrays and macros. *One call* to `diceRoll` would have shown you the problem.

Comment: @Valinho sorry, the array size should be `DICE*6+1`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying problem has nothing to do with the title or most of the text. It is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @user3629249 If I have two dice I can dice the values from 2 to 12 and that makes for me 11 values that I can get.

Comment: when a value is being incremented, that value needs to be initialized.  suggest 'sum = 0;'

Comment: @Beta I will keep this in mind for the future thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the value of `sum` in your function (preferably to 0), otherwise it will hold some garbage value.

```
int diceRoll(int dice)
{
 int sum;
 for(int i = 0; i < dice; i++)
  {
   sum += rand() % 6 + 1;
 }
 return sum;
}
```

The garbage value may be a very large number, and so will be the returned value of the function. So, when the returned value is used in this line:

```
int index = diceRoll(DICE) - DICE;
```

then the array will have an index of that large number, `valuesOfRoll[some_large_integer]++;`. This causes an out-of-array-bound situation, and causes seg-fault.

Comment: Thank you too for your effort and explanation. This solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize sum in the function diceRoll(),

```
/* always return value between [dice..dice*6]*/
int diceRoll(int dice)
{
  int sum=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < dice; i++)
  {
    sum += rand() % 6 + 1;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Since sum could have any value (on the stack), you were using an index value that could fall outside the ValuesOfRoll[] array.  One way to avoid is to use the modulus operator to limit the returned index to a valid range.

```
int main(void)
{
  srand(time(0));
  int valuesOfRoll[DICEEYES] = { 0 };
  for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
  {
    int index = diceRoll(DICE) - DICE;
    /* limit index to [0..DICEEYES] */
    index %= DICEEYES;
    valuesOfRoll[index]++;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < DICEEYES; i++)
  {
    if(valuesOfRoll[i] < 1) continue;
    printf("The number %d was rolled %4d times", i + DICE, valuesOfRoll[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen this mistake. This solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly belatedly, the faults are not initialising `sum`, and `DICEEYES`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DICE      2
#define DICEEYES  (DICE * 6)
#define COUNT     10000

int diceRoll(int dice)
{
    int i, sum = 0;                         // need to initialise!
    for(i = 0; i < dice; i++)
        sum += rand() % 6 + 1;
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int valuesOfRoll[DICEEYS+1] = { 0 };     // size of array
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        valuesOfRoll[diceRoll(DICE)]++;

    for(i = DICE; i <= DICEEYES; i++)
        printf("The number %2d was rolled %4d times\n", i, valuesOfRoll[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
The number  2 was rolled  264 times
The number  3 was rolled  573 times
The number  4 was rolled  798 times
The number  5 was rolled 1145 times
The number  6 was rolled 1373 times
The number  7 was rolled 1697 times
The number  8 was rolled 1385 times
The number  9 was rolled 1143 times
The number 10 was rolled  835 times
The number 11 was rolled  528 times
The number 12 was rolled  259 times
```

Comment: But in this case you are creating two arrays which aren't really used the [0] and [1] element.

Comment: There is only one array.

Comment: You are right, I mean two elements which are not used.

Comment: Yes, but the thing I want to point out that my solution is not wrong. By the way I am wondering why the middle values are always the highest.

Comment: Because of the perms. There is one way to make `2` (1+1) and `12` (6+6). There are more ways to make `7` (1+6) or (2+5) or (3+4) or (4+3) or (5+2) or (6+1). That's why `7` is 6 times more frequent than `2` or `12`.

Comment: there is a (very unlikely) chance that all the dice rolls yield the same pair of numbers, say 5, so the value format needs to allow for the max number of characters.  (and still keep everything vertically aligned) so the format for the value should be %5d

Comment: IMO:  bad coding practice to try and avoid using prototypes.  (compile parameter '-Wstrict-prototypes' will flag such practices.)   bad coding practice placing more than one statement on a line (the variables 'i' and 'sum')

Answer (score 0):

the following code

```
1) cleanly compiles
2) has corrections to the output formatting
3) properly initializes values (good case for always initialize all values)
4) outputs the proper data
5) does not try to fiddle offset/indexes, etc
6) uses meaningful #define names, function parameter names, etc

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_DICE           (2)
#define NUM_ROLLS          (10000)
#define MIN_DICEROLL_VALUE (2)
#define MAX_DICEROLL_VALUE (12)

int diceRoll(int numDice);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int valuesOfRoll[MAX_DICEROLL_VALUE+1] = { 0 }; // notice the +1

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ROLLS; i++)
    {
        int index = diceRoll(NUM_DICE);
        valuesOfRoll[index]++;
    }

    for(int i = MIN_DICEROLL_VALUE; i <= MAX_DICEROLL_VALUE; i++)
    {
        // 2d for values 2...12  5d for values 0...10000  \n so each output on anew line
        printf("The number %2d was rolled %5d times\n", i, valuesOfRoll[i]);
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main


int diceRoll(int numDice)
{
    int sum = 0;  // be sure to initialize value

    for(int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
        sum += (rand() % 6) + 1;
    }
    return sum;
} // end of function: diceRoll
```

Comment: note that the first two entries in the 'valueOfRolls[]' array are not actually used.  Not using those two values makes the code much easier to code/read/understand

Comment: You should cast the return value from `time` to justify your claim of a clean compilation.

Comment: To be a general solution, `MIN_DICEROLL_VALUE` and `MAX_DICEROLL_VALUE` should be defined as `(DICE)` and `(DICE*6)` respectively: bad coding pratice.